# Multiple if instances occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a dynamic page using clone property.

The problem occurs when I create say 4 Assured elements and when I close the first Assured (i.e) **Assured 1**, the close if statement occurs multiple times based on the **nth-element** value (hopefully).

I would like only one loop to occur such that the **id--** occurs only once...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = 1;
  var assured = document.getElementById('assuredconb');

  $('.add-contact').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (id < 5) {
      $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#assured' + id + '">New assured ' + id + '</a><span class="fas fa-times-circle close" id="close' + id + '"></span></li>');
      var clone = assured.cloneNode(true);
      clone.id = "assured" + id;
      $('.tab-content').append(clone);
      id++;
    }

    $('.close').click(function() {
      id--;
      var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
      $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
      $(this).parent().remove();
      $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
      alert(id);
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.close {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 25%;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  width: 175px;
  text-align: center;
}

.add-contact {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#assuredconx">Mr.X</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#assuredconb">Mr.Boy</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" class="add-contact" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="assuredconx" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade in active">#1</div>
    <div id="assuredconb" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade">#2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one event handler inside another. Every time you click on `.add-contact` you'll add another click handler to `.close`.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for the duplicate question